# Add y-axis for histogram in existing figure

Tags: matlab, histogram, distribution, figure

I have an existing figure which contains a histogram and a distribution function.
The figure was generated with MATLAB's Distribution Fitter App:

[image: Figure from Distribution Fitter App with single y-axis]

However, the figure doesn't contain an y-axis for the histogram, only one for the distribution function, which is on the left, with values [0, 0.05 ... 0.2].
The y-axis for the histogram should be approx. [0 ... 40].

I can't post example code, since, as I said, I only have the existing figure from the App and no code or data.

Is there a possibility to add that missing y-axis to an existing figure?

EDIT: Here's the .fig file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jK6ZxZ13p-w9GyeNUXSc5e0lKQE7XgRX

Comment: If you can not access the code, you can not modify the code, so we can not help with your code (which is the purpose of StackOverflow).

Comment: What your question though?

Comment: @AnderBiguri I see your point, but I was hoping someone could help me "develop" code, that is capable of doing what I need.

Comment: @RealReza The question is: How to add the y-axis to a figure that was generated with MATLAB's Distribution Fitter App?

Comment: You could load the figure and see what properties are available. I don't know how much it matters that the figure was generated by the Distribution Fitter App and don't know whether if it's possible to get the absolute counts in each histogram bin.

Comment: can you link the .fig file ?

Comment: @bla Sure! I edited the original question and put in the link.

Comment: Unfortunately - please correct me if I am wrong - the take away message seems to be, that the original histogram information cannot be cleanly reconstructed if the figure was made with the Distribution Fitter App. Thanks for your help everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The information that is saved in the fig file regarding the histogram (bars) is obtained by:

```
uiopen('t_2k_stack.fig',1);
h = gca;
y = h.Children(2).YData;
x = h.Children(2).XData;

figure(2)
plot(x,y)
```

as you can see, the information is already normalized to the same units of the d.f.. The original information (if there was one) was not saved in the figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Distribution Fitter tool open, go ahead and do whatever you want there. (Yes, Distribution Fitter plot y axis as probabilities or proportions of observations.)

Then, from the main menu of Distribution Fitter, click "File" > "Generate Code ...". MATLAB (at least 2020a on-line) will create a function that contains the raw source code without needing the tool. From here you can create and customize your own figure as you see fit.

Comment: As I said, I only have the figure, so I can't open Distribution Fitter and do it again.